# How is static intent received with no intent-filter in manifest file?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-widget, intentfilter

I am reviewing a widget application that updates stock price everytime a widget refresh button is clicked. The class com.github.premnirmal.ticker.widget.RefreshReceiver is the broadcast receiver that is launched in this instance. I do not know how this is happening as the manifest file does not include any intent-filers for the receiver?

I believe this is a statically registered receiver as the refresh intent is received even when the app isn't running.

Below is the snippets of relevant code. Full code can be found at https://github.com/premnirmal/StockTicker. Is there something i am missing here?

```
class RefreshReceiver : BroadcastReceiver(), CoroutineScope {

  @Inject internal lateinit var stocksProvider: IStocksProvider

  override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
    get() = Dispatchers.Main

  override fun onReceive(
      context: Context,
      intent: Intent
  ) {
    Injector.appComponent.inject(this)
    launch {
      stocksProvider.fetch()
    }
  }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.github.premnirmal.tickerwidget">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="androidx.browser,com.google.firebase.iid"/>
    <application
        android:name="com.github.premnirmal.ticker.StocksApp"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="android:icon">

        <activity
            android:exported="true"
            android:name="com.github.premnirmal.ticker.home.SplashActivity"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:exported="true"
            android:name="com.github.premnirmal.ticker.home.ParanormalActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
            android:theme="@style/ParanormalActivityTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.github.premnirmal.ticker.portfolio.AddPositionActivity"
            android:label="@string/add_position"
            android:theme="@style/AddPositionTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.github.premnirmal.ticker.portfolio.AddNotesActivity"
            android:label="@string/add_notes"
            android:theme="@style/AddPositionTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.github.premnirmal.ticker.portfolio.AddAlertsActivity"
            android:label="@string/add_alerts"
            android:theme="@style/AddPositionTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
        <activity
            android:exported="true"
            android:name="com.github.premnirmal.ticker.settings.WidgetSettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/action_Settings"
            android:theme="@style/WidgetSettingsTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.github.premnirmal.ticker.portfolio.search.SearchActivity"
            android:label="@string/action_search"
            android:theme="@style/SearchTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.github.premnirmal.ticker.news.QuoteDetailActivity"
            android:label="@string/news_feed"
            android:theme="@style/NewsFeedActivityTheme"
            android:parentActivityName="com.github.premnirmal.ticker.home.ParanormalActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.github.premnirmal.ticker.news.GraphActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:theme="@style/GraphActivityTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.github.premnirmal.ticker.debug.DbViewerActivity"
            android:theme="@style/DbViewerTheme" />

        <receiver
            android:name="com.github.premnirmal.ticker.UpdateReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.github.premnirmal.ticker.widget.RefreshReceiver"
            android:enabled="true" />
        <receiver
            android:name="com.github.premnirmal.ticker.notifications.DailySummaryNotificationReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" />

        <receiver
            android:name="com.github.premnirmal.ticker.widget.WidgetClickReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.github.premnirmal.ticker.WIDGET_CLICK" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:exported="true"
            android:name="com.github.premnirmal.ticker.widget.StockWidget"
            android:label="@string/widget_label">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/widget" />
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name="com.github.premnirmal.ticker.widget.RemoteStockProviderService"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_REMOTEVIEWS" />

        <!-- File provider -->
        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.crashlytics.ApiKey"
            android:value="856c59cfad291a9403df034e02e90219acfdedb1" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

```
  private fun updateWidget(
    context: Context,
    appWidgetId: Int,
    remoteViews: RemoteViews,
    appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager
  ) {
    val updateReceiverIntent = Intent(context, RefreshReceiver::class.java)
    updateReceiverIntent.action = AppPreferences.UPDATE_FILTER
    val refreshPendingIntent =
      PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
          context.applicationContext, 0, updateReceiverIntent,
          PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE or PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
      )
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.refresh_icon, refreshPendingIntent)
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, remoteViews)
  }
```

Comment: The `AppWidgetProvider` and its associated code is using a `PendingIntent` to indicate what to do when the app widget is clicked. A `PendingIntent` is not limited to manifest-registered receivers.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have added the pendingIngIntent you refer to. When i replicate this code i still do not get the widget refreshing. How can i have the widget refresh while the app is not running?

Comment: What you have should work fine for that. Your testing may be running into some problems. For example, some devices have "task killer" sorts of pre-installed apps that do the equivalent of "Force Stop" in the Settings apps. This will stop your `PendingIntent` from working, but that is not unique to your app. Also note that you either need to do your work synchronously in `onReceive()` (if it is cheap) or use something else that will keep your process around to do the work.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks again for your help. I have been stuck on this for days and still can't don't understand how the widget is refreshing after the app has been closed (swipe off the app in recents menu). Do you know how i can implement such functionality or know of any articles that explain how to do this? Please let me know if I should create separate thread for this.

Comment: First, test with another app on the same device that you are using for testing your own app. Find an app that also react to clicks on app widgets, and see if it also reacts after you swipe the app off of the overview/recent-apps screen. If that app also has problems, then the issue is more with your device and manufacturer decisions, and there is not much you can do about that. If, on the other hand, the other app still works, then something is different between your app and that one, and perhaps we can figure out what that might be.